# How To Close Login Form In 3 Attempts

Tags: c#

How to close login form if the user failed to login 3 times. What should I do to my code to achieve it?

```
if (user == "Admin" && pass == "Admin")
{

    //if user and pass are correct
    MessageBox.Show("Admin Access", "Access Granted",
    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

    //will transfer to the next form
    frmItems frmitem = new frmItems();
    frmitem.Show();
    this.Hide();
}
else
{
    //to make the textbox null if the pass is wrong
    txtUser.Text = "";
    txtPass.Text = "";
    count = 0;
    count++;

    //if the user or pass are wrong
    MessageBox.Show("Invalid User/Passwosrd", "Access Denied",
    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

    /close the program if the pass/user failed 3 times
    if (count == 3)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("This program will close", "Access Denied",
        MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
    }      
}
```

Comment: If   `count` is defined outside this scope then remove the line `count = 0;`, then your code will works fine

Comment: No problem, happy to help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now, you are making it inside the function because of which everytime the variable is set back to 0.

You just need to set the value of count to 0 where you are defining it. Hope you have made your count variable as global variable.

Comment: Is there anything more than my comment?

Comment: It was simultaneous and you didnot mention about making the variable global if he missed that.